# dotnetnuke and sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, dotnetnuke

Is it possible to integrate sharepoint into a site that was developed in dotnetnuke?

I did find on sourceforge [sharepointnuke](http://sharepointnuke.codeplex.com/releases/view/11436). Though it seems to only display specific lists. Would this be all i need?

Secondly... it looks like the more i research this.. people suggest Sharepoint is better for intranet use.. and DNN is better for internet facing websites.  (saying that sharepoint lacks the complete control needed that DNN can offer)

The question remains... is it still possible to have a DNN website.. and integrate sharepoint in for its intranet functionalities?

I will update this question as i learn/research more.

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean running both under the same site:

The way sharepoint runs, with the unmanaged code and strict IIS configurations in the Virtual Application, I would say it might be easier to run DotNetNuke *inside* SharePoint, not the other way around.

Just like with MVC, you would extract the DNN files in a folder like 12/TEMPLATES/LAYOUTS/DNN or inside the inetpub folder where the sharepoint site is configured and then go into trial and error from there. (Enable the CallStack and Debug attributes on SharePoint's web.config, also set CustomErrors to off)

If you want sharepoint in a internal host but somehow consume DNN (or is that the other way?) this would require to code against their APIs to read the data. SharePoint has a built-in RSS reader web part for example, that you can connect to DNN.

Comment: I think the short answer to my question is... not easily.  Thanks for your input :)